# How access TwiML bins?

Tags: twilio

Twilio made an update to their UI. I can no longer find how to edit my current TwiML bins. Where can I edit my TwiML bins? I've tried looking through dashboard with no such luck.

Update: I just typed "TwiML Bin" in search input while in the dashboard and was able to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

TwiML Bins are within the Runtime section of the console: https://www.twilio.com/console/runtime/twiml-bins

[image]

Hope that helps.